# change location of Js/CSS files location on request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting

I have few css and js files which I am using like below

```
~/css/style.css
~/js/script.js
```

And I have around 2000 css and js files included in around 100 pages.

So after uploading it on server, ~ behaves to domain and working.

but now I have to change the location for css and js files to cdn for servers.

So What I am thinking to do some url rewritting or transformation of url on request.
like when system requesting js files

```
https://js/script.js
```

it should replace and should be looking for

```
https://cdn.com/js/script.js
```

I tried url rewritting and not able to get it work..

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: where is the rule. you have not mentioned in the question.

Comment: You can open the pages in a text editor or visual studio and do a search and replace on all open documents.

Comment: Have you tried something like that: https://marisks.net/2017/05/14/changing-static-resource-urls-to-cdn-urls-with-url-rewrite/